# Uncenter vertically cell table content Latex

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I need the text in every column aligned at the top.

[image]

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{até 1989}                                         & \textbf{1990 a 1999}                                         & \textbf{2000 a 2009}                                               & \textbf{2010 a 2019
}                                                            \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Década de 70:}\\
Surge a\\
terotecnologia com\\
práticas aplicáveis\\
aos ativos físicos na\\
fase de manutenção\\
(instalação,\\
comissionamento,\\
manutenção e\\
substituição)\\ \\ \\ Até final da década\\
de 80:\\
O termo gestão de\\
ativos estava\\
associado ao setor\\
financeiro (business\\
economics)\\
\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Década de 90:\\
A gestão de ativos\\
começou a ser\\
associada ao\\
planejamento e\\
manutenção da\\
condição e do\\
desempenho de\\
ativos físicos e de\\
infraestrutura\\ \\ \\ Demanda crescente\\
por boas práticas e\\
diretrizes na\\
abordagem da gestão\\
de ativos ao longo de\\
todo ciclo de vida\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2004 a 2008:\\
Publicação da PAS\\
55 pelo IAM e BSI\\
(primeira versão em\\
2004 e segunda em\\
2008) para a gestão\\
do ciclo de vida do\\
ativo
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 5\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}6\\ \\ 7\\ \\ 8\\ \\ 9\\ \\ 10\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! replace inner table position options from `c` to `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)-based solution, with automatic linebreaking enabled and with a target width of `\textwidth`. Note that I've done away with almost all hard-coded line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % better handling of accented characters
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress full justification

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LLL c @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{até 1989} & \textbf{1990 a 1999} & \textbf{2000 a 2009} & \textbf{2010 a 2019} \\ 
\midrule

\textbf{Década de 70:}

\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}

Surge a terotecnologia com práticas aplicáveis aos ativos físicos na fase de manutenção (instalação, comissionamento, manutenção e substituição)

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

Até final da década de 80:

\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}

O termo gestão de ativos estava associado ao setor financeiro (business economics)
& 
Década de 90:

\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}

A gestão de ativos começou a ser associada ao planejamento e manutenção da condição e do desempenho de ativos físicos e de infraestrutura

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

Demanda crescente por boas práticas e diretrizes na abordagem da gestão de ativos ao longo de todo ciclo de vida
& 
2004 a 2008:

\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}

Publicação da PAS 55 pelo IAM e BSI (primeira versão em 2004 e segunda em 2008) para a gestão do ciclo de vida do ativo 

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

5
&
% final column
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
   6\\ \\ 7\\ \\ 8\\ \\ 9\\ \\ 10
\end{tabular} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I`m new to Latex and your answer easy to understand and adapt.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler solution is replace inner table position options from c to t
but nicer result you may get, if you omit inner tables. For example by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec   = {@{} *{3}{X[cmd={\RaggedRight}]} Q[c] @{}},
             row{1,2}  = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
até 1989  
    &   1990 a 1999 
        &   2000 a 2009 
            &   2010 a 2019                     \\
    \midrule
Década de 70:
    &   Década de 90:
        &   2004 a 2008
            &                                   \\
Surge a terotecnologia com práticas aplicáveis
aos ativos físicos na fase de manutenção (instalação,
comissionamento, manutenção e substituição)
    &   A gestão de ativos começou a ser associada ao planejamento e manutenção da condição e do desempenho de ativos físicos e de infraestrutura
        &   Publicação da PAS 55 pelo IAM e BSI (primeira versão em 2004 e segunda em 2008) para a gestão do ciclo de vida do    ativo
            &   {6\\[2ex] 7\\[2ex] 8\\[2ex] 9\\[2ex] 10}            \\
Até final da década de 80:\par
O termo gestão de ativos estava associado ao setor financeiro (business economics)
    &   Demanda crescente por boas práticas e diretrizes na abordagem da gestão de ativos ao longo de todo ciclo de vida
        &   5   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you'll get better line breaks if you provide the instruction `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}`.

Comment: @Mico, you are right, but I didn't know which language OP use: portuguese or spanish ... Thank you for help.  Considered now.